# How to clear history in Ubuntu Web Browser

Tags: webbrowser-app

I'm using Ubuntu Web Browser (webbrowser-app) in 14.04, and I can't find a way to clear history. Can someone tell me how to clear history?

Comment: You can try by opening up browser settings and navigate to privacy. Or, you can tap ctrl+shift+del button simultaneously to purge the history!

Answer (score 2):

I found it at `/home/myaccountnamestuff/.local/share/webbrowser-app/Cache2`

The sqlite files have history content.